# Wireshark seems to ignore my filters

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture

I'm trying to make use of Wireshark 1.10.6 for Windows and I want to only capture the traffic to port 443 (to diagnose some weird HTTPS problems I'm having). So I open *Capture* -> *Capture Filters...* and in there I delete all filters and then add one filter with filter string set to *port 443*. Then I start the capture and see that there's a lot of unrelated stuff captured, for example this one

> BROWSER 243 Host Announcement , Workstation, Server, SQL Server, NT Workstation, NT Server, Backup Browser, DFS server

so it looks like the capture filters are ignored.

What am I doing wrong and how do I make use of filters?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created your Capture Filter using *Capture -> Capture Filters...* you have to define it in the Capture Options.

1. Open *Capture -> Options...*
2. Click on the `Capture Filter` button
3. Select the filter you want then click `OK`
4. Start the capture

Now it should be filtered using one of these filter strings :

- `port 443`
- `tcp port 443`

Further infos in the user guide : [Filtering while capturing](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCapCaptureFilterSection.html).

Comment: Great, now it filters everything out even if I craft a `port 443` filter and open `https://github.com` in Firefox.

Comment: @sharptooth Make sure you are filtering/capturing on the right ethernet interface, in case you have more than one. Also check that the filter string is correct. But `port 443` or `tcp port 443` should work

Comment: @sharptooth So, what about your filters now ?

Comment: They don't look working.

Comment: @sharptooth Seriously ?? Did you check what i said about the right interface ?

Comment: Yeap, I only have one interface and capture works if I simply remove the filter. That's something stupid but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark 2.2.1 seems broken with capture filters. What you're supposed to do is go to:

Capture -> Capture Filters...

Add your filters, then go to:

Capture -> Options -> select loopback -> scrolll ALLLL the way to the right, click the drop down box and select your capture filter name, or type the name in.

THIS DOES NOT WORK. None of the capture filters display, typing the filters in directly, it still cannot locate them.

The way i ended up doing it, and it seems to kind of work, is by exiting wireshark, starting it up you get a prompt which asks you for your wireshark capture filter then entering your filter of "port 18080 or port 18081 or port 1883 and tcp", or whatever, just put the filter in there and double click loopback or whatever and that seems to work.

Just a thought, is it just broken under windows? Maybe some configuration or path option prevents the capture filters being found??